# Ivars type Nsstring in Obejctive c are nil after button event

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, setting, ivars

I dont understand this yet. If I create an ivar of a class (no property). I set the ivar directly to for example `@"patrik"` in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` then the ivar value is still there when I click a button and checks for the Ivar value in the handler.

BUT!
If I have two buttons.
I set the ivar directly in the first button handler that I fire with a click. And then I check the Ivar in the second button handler that i fire. Then the ivar i empty?

Can someone explain what is happining?

Here is the code. Dead simple:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   Ivar=@"Patrik";      
   [super viewDidLoad];
}



- (IBAction)secondButtonHandler: (id)sender{

   NSString *result=Ivar;

}


- (IBAction)firstButtonHandler: (id)sender{


}
```

Here the Ivar is still here when I press the second button.

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   [super viewDidLoad];
}



- (IBAction)secondButtonHandler: (id)sender{

   NSString *result=Ivar;


}


- (IBAction)firstButtonHandler: (id)sender{

   Ivar=@"Patrik";      
}
```

But here its not after I have pressed the first button and then the second!?

Comment: Would need to see code. That said, I would just use a property.